# Is there a way to do a post in PHP

Tags: php, facebook, post

I am trying to do a simple post to facebook, I got same sample to do a postcode and I changed it a little.

I get the following error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /home/consult/public_html/projects/facebook/index.php on line 13

the line is

```
'access_token'=>;urlencode($code),
```

the code:

```
<?php
//set POST variables
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/arjun/feed';
$code="testing";
$message="Test";
$fields = array(
    'access_token'=>;urlencode($code),
    'message'=>;urlencode($message),
                );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=&gt;$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&amp;'; }
rtrim($fields_string,'&amp;');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

//execute post
// $result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);


?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be

```
  'access_token'=>urlencode($code),
```

not

```
 'access_token'=>;urlencode($code),
```

also,

```
'message'=>;urlencode($message),
```

should be

```
'message'=>urlencode($message),
```

also,

```
key=&gt;
```

should be

```
key=>
```

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: It wasn't so hard, even in that mess

Comment: @genesis φ Why not help him out by **pointing to all of the errors**?

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for showing me the typo in the code
Unforchently I’m not a PHP programmer.  I was trying to search on google for sample code, which had the typo. For a PHP programmer looks like the typo would seem like a silly mistake.

Comment: @salathe: there are no more syntax errors, `@Ted don't forgot to uncomment your curl_exec